# Spring Cloud Gateway not working with HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

When using Spring Cloud Gateway with `server.ssl.enabled=true`, I get: `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`
*Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.*

Only disabling SSL I can use the gateway(`server.ssl.enabled=false`)

How can I force using HTTPS through the Spring Cloud Gateway?

The complete source code including the discovery service and a demo users-ws at: https://github.com/bcfernandez/Demo-SpringCloud.git

The users-ws entry point is working using HTTPS: https://localhost:8181/users/status
However, when I try to reach the users-ws through the gateway (https://localhost:8011/users/v1/status
), I get`ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

The gateway app.properties is the following:

```
server.port=8011
spring.application.name=trm-api-gateway
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true

# WARNING: TO BE REMOVED ON PRODUCTION
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true

#Routes filtering
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-service_v1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users/v1/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=/users/v1(?<segment>/?.*), /users${segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://users-ws

#WARNING: TO BE REMOVED ON PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT
#Using an insecure trust manager is not suitable for production. For a production deployment, you can     configure the gateway with a set of known certificates that it can trust 
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.ssl.useInsecureTrustManager=true

# Eureka Info
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true

#SSL Key Info
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=mySelfSignedKey
server.ssl.key-store-password=password@2020
server.ssl.key-store=myKeyStore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12

# Properties set for development purposes only
logging.level.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=DEBUG
debug=true
```